# Cover time chess board (king)

Tags: probability-theory, graph-theory

Consider a random walk of a king on a standard chess board, which at each step moves to a uniformly random permitted square.  What's the exact mean time to visit all squares (cover time), starting from a corner square?

Is there an algebraic solution?

Comment: Here is a relevant quote from Chapter 12 of *Problems and Snapshots from the World of Probability* by Blom, Holst, and Sandell. "This problem seems extremely difficult. According to simulation, consisting of one million rounds, the mean is approximately equal to 615."

Comment: @Byron: Strangely, the problem is underspecified in the book: "Place a king *somewhere* on an empty chessboard." From mjqxxxx's results from $597$ to $621$, it seems that the initial position might be meant to be selected at random.

Comment: @joriki Yes, that makes sense.

Comment: What are the asymptotics for the mean time for an nxn board?

Answer (score 8):

There is *in principle* no difficulty in answering this question.
As I point out in my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89548/famous-uses-of-the-inclusion-exclusion-principle/89706#89706), calculating the expected cover 
time of some set $\cal S$ reduces to calculating the expected hitting time  of every possible non-empty subset $A$ of $\cal S$:

$$\mathbb{E}(\text{cover time})=\sum_A (-1)^{|A|-1} \mathbb{E}(T_A)$$

These hitting times are defined by $T_A=\inf(n\geq 0: X_n\in A)$.

---

**Look out below!** Ignorant of chess rules, I didn't realize that a king can move diagonally. The calculations below are based on a piece that can only move in four ways: north, south, east, or west.

---

Just to illustrate, let me show you the solution for a $2\times 2$ chessboard:

[image: a small board]

The expected time to cover the other 3 squares ${a,b,c}$ is equal to 
$$\mathbb{E}(T_{a})+\mathbb{E}(T_{b})+\mathbb{E}(T_{c})-\mathbb{E}(T_{a,b})-\mathbb{E}(T_{a,c})-\mathbb{E}(T_{b,c})+\mathbb{E}(T_{a,b,c})$$

Standard Markov chain theory uses linear algebra to find these expected hitting times
$$\mathbb{E}(T_{a})=\mathbb{E}(T_{c})=3, \mathbb{E}(T_{b})=4, 
\mathbb{E}(T_{a,b})=\mathbb{E}(T_{b,c})=2, \mathbb{E}(T_{a,c})=\mathbb{E}(T_{a,b,c})=1$$

Putting it all together, we find that the expected cover time is $3+3+4-2-2-1+1=6$.

Note that I counted the king's initial position as already covered. If you 
 require a return to your starting point you can modify the above technique.

The number of terms in the sum make this method impractical for an $8\times 8$ chessboard, however!

---

**Added:** If my calculations are correct, the expected cover time for the $3\times 3$ board is $${140803109038245\over 4517710919176}=31.1669$$

Comment: Hmmm, now my link is also messed up.

Comment: I don't know which of my minor changes (mainly removing periods from inside Latex expressions) did anything, but things look okay to me now.

Comment: You cut your hair. :-(

Comment: It's my new look.

Answer (score 2):

There *is* an algebraic solution; the mean cover time from any node in a graph is known to be rational and can be found in exponential time.  It's not likely to have a simple form, though.  Experimentally, I ran the following code:

```
import random

def reachable((i,j)):
   ok = lambda(q):(min(q)>=1 and max(q)<=8)
   return filter(ok, [(i-1,j-1), (i-1,j), (i-1,j+1), (i,j-1), (i,j+1), (i+1,j-1), (i+1,j), (i+1,j+1)])

def covertime(sq, rng=random.Random()):
   seen = set([sq])
   path = [sq]
   while len(seen)<64:
      path.append(rng.choice(reachable(path[-1])))
      seen.add(path[-1])
   return len(path)-1
```

I found that the mean cover time starting from a corner square was about $597$, while the mean cover time starting from a center square was larger, about $621$.