# How do you find the expected Cover Time of a graph?

Tags: graph-theory, random-walk

I can only find resources that give an upper bound on the cover time, but not how to find the exact expected cover time of a graph. Somebody told me it's related to the coupon collector problem, but I have no idea how to use this information. Also is solving for the cover time a different procedure depending on whether the graph is ergodic or not? Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The difficulty will depend very much on the kind of graph. Here is an example: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286739/cover-time-chess-board-king/286871#286871

Comment: Is there any type of general procedure or place to start? I have a test coming up where a possible question might be to find the expected cover time and I have no idea where to start. The only thing I know for sure about the graphs is that the number of vertices will be small.

Comment: My answer linked to above has an explicit formula. I worked out the details in a very small case.